# Angular UI-Slider

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am trying to use the angular-ui slider from here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider

I have included jquery, jquery-ui and angular files.
I have also included the css files.

However the slider does not get displayed on the page..

Anyone has any clue what I am missing here ?

Here is a plunkr:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/w5aQ61wAoP8bbAcAfR5F?p=preview
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the AngularJS script below the jQuery.

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9OpPvGUr4p2yeEpiy8wC?p=preview)

The order you include your scripts matters when using jQuery with AngularJS.

The [FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) isn't exactly clear

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

The translation is basically, if you have jQuery included before angular loads it will use that version.  Otherwise it will fallback to jQlite and ignore any others that come after.

Comment: Any other ideas?  I'm having a similar issue, but have my includes in the order suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

You might have missed the module dependency on your app declaration?

Make sure you have:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.slider']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the order of the scripts (e.g. because of your build process), you can fix this within the directive. The **elm** variable contains a jquery-lite object and the full-featured jquery is available as **$**. So you can simply "upgrade" the elm:

```
elm = $(elm)
```

From then on, elm has the *slider()* method.

Also, don't forget to include styles for the slider has it would be hidden otherwise.